# TFlite model.process() sometimes needs input data TensorImage and sometimes TensorBuffer to process an image? Are there different image input data?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Some TFlite models model.process() seems to need TensorBuffer  and other rather needs TensorImage . I don't know why?

First, I took a regular TensorFlow / Keras model that was saved using:

```
model.save(keras_model_path,
    include_optimizer=True, 
    save_format='tf')
```

Then I compress and quantize this Keras model (300 MB) to a TFlite format using:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(keras_model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(dir_val,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    image_size=(150,150))
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open(tflite_model_path, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(tflite_model)
```

I've got a lot smaller TFlite model (40 Mo) which needs **TensorBuffer** <input_data> when calling model.process(<input_data>)

Second, I've trained and saved as TFLite model using TensorFlow Lite Model Maker and now I've got a TFLite model that needs **TensorImage** <input_data> when calling model.process(<input_data>).

Are there two different TFlite models depending on how you build and train it?

Maybe it's related to the fact that the Keras model was based on Inception and the TensorFlow Lite Model Maker uses EfficientNet. How convert from one TFlite model to the other? How someone can change the input of images to be able to process the same, for example TensorImage or bitmap data input?

Comment: No it is not due to different Backbones. Your first example is of this category
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/lite_support#create_output_objects_and_run_the_model
and your second is of this:
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android/EXPLORE_THE_CODE.md
Either can be handled by Interpreter like:
interpreter.run(input.buffer,output.buffer)

You can always check the API to see if there is a different constructor that converts the TensorImage to ByteBuffer.

Comment: You can create an example github repo to showcase your 2 examples to help you understand more about the options you have to use the .tflite file.

Comment: @Farmaker Thanks for your help! A link to my GitHub repo https://github.com/ClaudeCoulombe/EcorcIA which is an update, adaptation with some French translation of the Google Developer Codelabs https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/recognize-flowers-with-tensorflow-on-android/#0. I've just tried to replace the TFlite model created and trained using TensorFlow Lite Model Maker by one from Keras CNN then converted and  quantized to TFLite.

Comment: @Farmaker Look at the MainActivity.kt file from line 100, ImageAnalyzer Class. The Keras CNN code is in a IPython Notebook https://github.com/ClaudeCoulombe/VIARENA/blob/master/Labos/Lab-Ecorces_Arbres/IdEcorces-ResConv-TransfertAmplication-Colab.ipynb

Comment: Maybe I have not understood exactly the problem. I want to ask if the model that you have created WITHOUT model maker, does it contain metadata? Have you inserted metadata? Because when you are creating a model with the model maker it automatically inserts metadata and can process the TensorImage directly by creating the bytebuffer internally based on the metadata. Check the documentation about the model maker and metadata which inserts when it exports to tflite file.

Comment: So I believe the solution is to add metadata at your first file that is not generated with the model maker by inserting them yourself 
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata

Answer (score 1):

With the very valuable help of [@Farmaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7118084/farmaker), I've solve my problem. I simply wanted to convert a `Keras` model into a more compact `TFlite` model to install it in a mobile application. I realized that the generated `TFlite` model was not compatible and @Farmaker pointed out to me very correctly that the metadata was missing.

1. You should use `TensorFlow` 2.6.0 or less because incompatibility with `Flatbuffer`.

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow
pip3 install tensorflow==2.6.0
pip3 install keras==2.6.0
```

2. Convert the Keras model to TFlite

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(keras_model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(dir_val,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    image_size=(150,150))
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open(tflite_model_path, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(tflite_model)
```

3. Add metadata as shown here in the « TensorFlow Lite Metadata Writer API » [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata_writer_tutorial)

  - 3.1 Provide a labels.txt file (a file of all the target class labels, one label by line)
    For instance, to create such a file,
    ```
    your_labels_list = [
        'class1','class2',...]
    with open('labels.txt', 'w') as labels_file:
        for label in your_labels_list:
            labels_file.write(label + "\n")
    ```
  - 3.2 Provide extra library to support TFlite metadata generation
    ```
    pip3 install tflite-support-nightly
    ```
  - 3.3 Generate the metadata
    ```
    from tflite_support.metadata_writers import image_classifier
    from tflite_support.metadata_writers import writer_utils

    ImageClassifierWriter = image_classifier.MetadataWriter
    # Normalization parameters are required when processing the image
    # https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata#normalization_and_quantization_parameters)
    _INPUT_NORM_MEAN = 127.5
    _INPUT_NORM_STD = 127.5
    _TFLITE_MODEL_PATH = "<your_path_to_model.tflite>"
    _LABELS_FILE = ""<your_path_to_labels.txt>""
    _TFLITE_METADATA_MODEL_PATHS = ""<your_path_to_model_with_metadata.tflite>""

    # Create the metadata writer
    metadata_generator = ImageClassifierWriter.create_for_inference(
        writer_utils.load_file(_TFLITE_MODEL_PATH), 
        [_INPUT_NORM_MEAN], [_INPUT_NORM_STD],
        [_LABELS_FILE])

    # Verify the metadata generated 
    print(metadata_generator.get_metadata_json())

    # Integrate the metadata into the TFlite model
    writer_utils.save_file(metadata_generator.populate(), _TFLITE_METADATA_MODEL_PATHS)
    ```

That's all folks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use tdfs, dataset, dataset_image, tf.constants, and other data formats.

You also can use tf.constants where you input required parameters OR you can input weights algorithms. ( Convolution layer also capable )

I determine the input and target response catagorizes.

**[ Sequence to Sequence mapping ]:**

```
group_1_ShoryuKen_Left = tf.constant([ 0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0 ], shape=(1, 1, 48), dtype=tf.float32)
# get_weights
layer1_lstm = model.get_layer( name="layer1_bidirection-lstm" )
lstm_weight_1 = layer1_lstm.get_weights()[0]
lstm_filter_1 = layer1_lstm.get_weights()[1]

# set weights
layer1_lstm =  model.get_layer( name="layer1_bidirection-lstm " )
layer1_conv.set_weights([lstm_weight_1, lstm_filter_1])
```

**[ TDFS ]:**

```
builder = tfds.builder('cats_vs_dogs', data_dir='file:\\\\F:\\datasets\\downloads\\PetImages\\')
ds = tfds.load('cats_vs_dogs', split='train', shuffle_files=True)
assert isinstance(ds, tf.data.Dataset)

data = DataLoader.from_folder('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\flower_photos\\')
train_data, test_data = data.split(0.9)

for example in ds.take(1):
  image, label = example["image"], example["label"]

model = image_classifier.create(train_data)
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8pzX.png)

Comment: Not quite this question but how do you call a TF Lite model with tf.Data.Dataset? I keep getting `TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` from the signature runner.